# C# language versioning when automatically selected based on framework version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have to update the C# version. Now, I use version 7.3 but I need to use 8 or greater version.

While applying the steps in this [link](https://www.techpointfunda.com/2020/08/change-csharp-version-visual-studio.html), I faced with the problem as it can be seen in the image.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Is there any way to make it manual instead of automatic?

Comment: So what happened when you clicked on the link immediately below the disabled control that purports to tell you why you cannot change the version?

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8), "C# 8.0 is supported on .NET Core 3.x and .NET Standard 2.1."

Comment: It's entirely possible to specify it in the project file though - at least with SDK-style projects. Just use `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>`.

Comment: I have not find a clear answer from the link

Comment: @JonSkeet, `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` this block of code should be written in App.config?

Comment: @NihadHuseynov: No, in the project file. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever When you click the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) it brings you to a page that does **not** explain why I can't selelct a different C# version.

Comment: @IanBoyd It literally explains it in the first sentence? *"The latest C# compiler determines a default language version based on your project's target framework or frameworks."* That is why you cannot change it. It is automatic now, unlike before. The very next sentence explains what to do: *"Visual Studio doesn't provide a UI to change the value, but you can change it by editing the csproj file."*

Comment: @Gserg Yes, **exactly**: *"The latest C# compiler determines a default language version based on your project's target framework or frameworks."* It's nice of it to try to automatically determine a langauge version based on my project's target framework. But the question was: how to change it. An alternate question would be *"Why can't I select a different C# version?"* Because...i **can** select a different C# version - so why can't i change it...there - on that screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you edit your .csproj add this line inside the first `<PropertyGroup>`

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

or if you want to specify the version

```
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
```

In other words:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{68EAC5EC-1EE6-4B41-BCF8-ED62CA1B6364}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>SqlServerCLRFunctions</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SqlServerCLRFunctions</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion> <!-- added, default is C# 7.3 -->
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You might add, to test this put `#error version` anywhere in the code and it'll give the version for the current project.